# Consulta linq, igualando propiedades

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework code first, estoy armando una consulta pero de mi entidad solo necesito los dos primeros atributos por la cual tuve que crear otra clase con los atributos que necesito para no traerme toda la entidad.

```
public class Proveedor
{
    public int ProveedorId { get; set; }
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    public string DocumentoIdentidad { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Fijo { get; set; }
    public string Celular { get; set; }
    public string Representante { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Marca> Marcas { get; set; }
}
```

Clase extendida

```
public class ProveedorExtend 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

Necesito igualar las propiedades

```
public IEnumerable<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(int? codigo, string nombre)
    {
        var result = (from p in Context.Proveedores
                      select new ProveedorExtend()
                      {
                          Id = p.ProveedorId,
                          Descripcion = p.RazonSocial
                      })
```

De tal manera que le pueda aplicar un Where

```
where ((!codigo.HasValue) || (p.Codigo.Contains(codigo.Value)))
                        && ((nombre == null) || (p.Nombre.Contains(nombre)))
                 select p).ToList();
```

Como puedo hacer esta query

```
public List<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(int? codigo, string nombre)
{
    using(DbContext context = new DbContext())
    {
        var result = (from p in context.Proveedores
                     where ((!Id.HasValue) || (p.Id.Contains(Id.Value)))
                            && ((Descripcion == null) || (p.Descripcion.Contains(nombre)))
                     select p).ToList();;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Pero necesito igualar las entidades antes de hacer esa consulta.
Espero haberme explicado.
**La descripción sería:** Trato de hacer una consulta que me sirva para dos condiciones mediante esa query puedo preguntar por el id, como puedo preguntar por la descripción, como por ejempo si tengo una tabla que tenga, 1-Juan 2-Miguel 3-Marcos 4- José. Lo que quiero es hacer un like, investigando constains es el que hace un like, pero el problema es que no puedo aplicarle a toda la entidad, si fuera SQL haria una consulta SELECT Id, descripcion FROM Proveedores, .... pero en EF no puedo hacer eso me traeria toda la entidad es por eso que tengo que separala en mi clase ProveedorExtend donde pongo los atributos que necesito pero para que funcione tengo que igualarla a la de Proveedores, en mi Context no me contempla ProveedorExtends no puedo aplicarla directamente.

Quedo la query gracias Leandro y Carlos Muñoz.

```
public IEnumerable<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(int? codigo, string nombre)
    {
        var result = (from p in Context.Proveedores
                      where ((!codigo.HasValue) || (p.ProveedorId == codigo.Value)) &&
                      ((nombre == null) || (p.RazonSocial.Contains(nombre)))
                      select new ProveedorExtend()
                      {
                          Id = p.ProveedorId,
                          Descripcion = p.RazonSocial
                      }).ToList();
        return result;          
    }
```

Comment: Hola Pedro, te faltó especificar cual es tu consulta. Por favor edita tu pregunta y añádela.

Comment: Cuál es la consulta?

Comment: Voy a modificar

Comment: Gracias por actualizar tu pregunta, pero, ¿puedes agregar una descripción de la consulta?

Comment: Actualizare la pregunta

Comment: porque en el where defines (!Id.HasValue) no deberia ser (!codigo.HasValue) ? lo que debes evaluar es al parametro se asigno un valor o sea ((!codigo.HasValue) || (p.Id.Contains(codigo.Value)))

Comment: Tienes razón Leandro debo evaluar los parametros voy a corregir

Comment: Implementado el código en la UI yo le voy a pasar parametros pero uno a la vez no dos al mismo tiempo, entonces necesito algo como esto public IEnumerable<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(ProveedorExtend filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria

```
public List<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(int? codigo, string nombre)
{
    using(DbContext context = new DbContext())
    {
        var result = (from p in context.Proveedores
                     where ((!Id.HasValue) || (p.Id.Contains(Id.Value)))
                            && ((Descripcion == null) || (p.Descripcion.Contains(nombre)))
                     select new ProveedorExtend()
                      {
                          Id = p.ProveedorId,
                          Descripcion = p.RazonSocial
                      }).ToList();;

        return result;
    }
}
```

como veras en el select defines el `new` de la clase `ProveedorExtend`

Comment: `p` no tiene ni las propiedades `Descripcion` ni `Id`. Esas propiedades corresponden a `ProveedorExtend`

Comment: Asi es, me acabo de dar cuenta de eso es mas a Id no le puedo hacer Id.Constains

Answer (score 1):

> Nota: Creo que tienes errores de sintaxis en tu código. Colocaré el código según como parece que debería ser.

Si necesitas convertir `Proveedor` en `ProveedorExtend` **antes** de aplicar el where te recomiendo la sintaxis usando lambdas:

```
public List<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(int? codigo, string nombre)
{
    using(DbContext context = new DbContext())
    {
        return context.Proveedores
            .Select(p => new ProveedorExtend
            {
                Id = p.ProveedorId,
                Descripcion = p.RazonSocial
            })
            .Where(p =>
                (!codigo.HasValue || p.Id == codigo.Value) &&
                (nombre == null || p.Descripcion.Contains(nombre)
            )
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Por otro esto no es necesario puedes aplicar el `.Where()` a la colección original y luego proyectar sus propiedades en la nueva clase.

```
public List<ProveedorExtend> SelectList(int? codigo, string nombre)
{
    using(DbContext context = new DbContext())
    {
        return context.Proveedores
            .Where(p =>
                (!codigo.HasValue || p.ProveedorId == codigo.Value) &&
                (nombre == null || p.RazonSocial.Contains(nombre)
            )
            .Select(p => new ProveedorExtend
            {
                Id = p.ProveedorId,
                Descripcion = p.RazonSocial
            })
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Me da error int no contiene una definición para Constains

Comment: Listo, ya que es `Id` o `ProveedorId` es de tipo `int` debes compararlo con `==`

Comment: Bien, pero no me contempla el select y con p ya no tengo navegabilidad no puedo ver ProveedorId ni RazonSocial

Comment: En cual de los dos casos?

Comment: En la segunda opción